# pass java integer array as arguments to postgres procedure

Tags: java, sql, arrays, database, postgresql

Defined java integer array as below,

```
Integer[] details = {5097, 5098, 5099, 5100, 5101, 5102, 5121, 5122, 5123, 5124, 5125, 5126, 5127, 5128, 5129, 5130};
```

Then converted java array to postgres type array using connection object as below,

```
connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(MySQLURL,"postgres","admin");
Array dArray = connection.createArrayOf("INT", details);
```

After that passed **dArray** as argument to postgres procedure as below,

```
String simpleProc = "{ call SMS.P_DELETE_DATA("+dArray+") }";
        CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(simpleProc);
        cs.execute();
```

I wrote postgres procedure signature as below,

```
CREATE FUNCTION SMS.P_DELETE_WORKPLAN_FOR_LESSON(P_LESSONS INT[]) 
 RETURNS VOID AS $$
```

But when i run the java code it throws **Malformed procedure / function call ......**

Some one advice me to sort out this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hełm, you should set the Parameter for Sql Statement with a Method and not in the sql String.
Try something like this:

```
        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(MySQLURL,"postgres","admin");
        Array dArray = connection.createArrayOf("INT", details);
        String simpleProc = "{ call SMS.P_DELETE_DATA(?) }";
        CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall(simpleProc);
        cs.setArray(1, dArray);
        cs.execute();
        cs.close();
```